# Is there a way to hide the Windows 7 taskbar permanently?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I've used ObjectDock in the past to replace the taskbar for a number of reasons. I had to reinstall Windows and apparently now ObjectDock is no longer free. One main reason I liked ObjectDock is because it completley replaces the taskbar, hiding the taskbar completely, not just autohiding it or hiding it till moving my mouse to the bottom, but actually completely removing it.

So clearly there is some way to hide it or move it so it doesn't show up in some way, but I've yet to find anything online that shows a way within Windows 7 or a programmatic way to do so. I've got most of my programs linked to hotkeys through AutoHotkey, and since my resolution is small I'd like the extra space.

Comment: Please ask at superuser.com and not here as this is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Try using either [Taskbar Eliminator](http://download.cnet.com/Taskbar-Eliminator/3000-18487_4-10908230.html) or [The Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-3-windows-8).  They should allow you to remove it, this should remove it for you.